# Using a docker-compose.yml in terraform

Tags: git, docker-compose, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm running terraform 0.13.2 on mac.  I am trying to create an azure app service that uses a docker-compose configuration (I'm wrapping a third-party docker image in an HTTP API).  As I understand it I need to put the contents of the docker-compose.yml into the app serviceas per this example:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "westeurope"
}

module "web_app_container" {
  source = "innovationnorway/web-app-container/azurerm"

  name = "hello-world"

  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  container_type = "compose"

  container_config = <<EOF
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: "innovationnorway/go-hello-world"
    ports:
     - "80:80"
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
EOF
}
```

Now I have the docker-compose.yml in source control.  So what I want to do is get the latest version of the docker-compose.yml (yes I appreciate this might have edges) and use that as the value of the `container_config` variable so I end up with something like:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "westeurope"
}

module "web_app_container" {
  source = "innovationnorway/web-app-container/azurerm"

  name = "hello-world"

  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  container_type = "compose"

  container_config = file("docker-compose.yml")

}
```

But I'm unclear how to get the file out of git or even use a private github repo so I get something like:

```
container_config = file(git@github.com:my-org/private-repo.git/docker-compose.yml)
```

Is that even possible?

Comment: Is there a reason your Docker-Compose file doesn't live with the Terraform code? And as far as I know there's no way to retrieve files from a Git repo other than via the [`http` data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/http/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source). The GitHub provider has a `repository_file` resource for creating and managing files in a repository but no data source to retrieve the contents of an existing file.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR the docker-compose.yml up to now has been living with the source code for the wrapper API.  Which seemed natural from a development POV.

Comment: Yes, but I'm asking why the Terraform code to deploy it can't also live there? I personally favour having the infrastructure code for a service live alongside the service code and think this solves a lot of other issues. Your other option is to have whatever runs your Terraform commands also clone (potentially as a submodule) the other repo. Or access it via the `http` data source but that looks like it might be a pain unless that repo is public.